# want to display all maximum 'levelNumber' of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, reduce

```
arr1 = [
{
    "levelNumber": "2",
    "name": "abc",
},
{
    "levelNumber": "3",
    "name": "abc"
},
{ 
    "levelNumber": "3",
    "name": "raks",
}
]
```

my result array should have objects with max levelNumber i.e 3 in this case.

it should look like:

```
resultArr = [
{
    "levelNumber": "3",
    "name": "abc"
},
{ 
    "levelNumber": "3",
    "name": "raks",
}
]
```

note that here levelNumber can be anything..
please help me with the generic nodejs code to get duplicate max value objects

Comment: Are you looking for max value and should be duplicate? Or only should be the max value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "levelNumber": "2",
        "name": "abc",
    },
    {
        "levelNumber": "3",
        "name": "abc"
    },
    { 
        "levelNumber": "3",
        "name": "raks",
    }
];

const levelNumbers = data.map((item) => parseInt(item.levelNumber));
const maxLevelNumber = Math.max(...levelNumbers).toString();

const highestLevelItems = data.filter((item) => item.levelNumber == maxLevelNumber);
console.log(highestLevelItems);

/* output
  [
    { levelNumber: '3', name: 'abc' },
    { levelNumber: '3', name: 'raks' }
  ]
*/
```

---

**EDIT**

As @nat mentioned in comment:

> if I add one more object in the array, with `name = 'raks & levelNumber = '4'` then it should display maximum levelNumber wrt that particular name. i.e.
> `{ "levelNumber": "3", "name": "abc" }, { "levelNumber": "4", "name": "raks" }`

To achieve this, you have to:

1. make a `Set` of names
2. make a separate empty array to hold final result
3. repeat the above process for each name and add result in the array
4. return complete result

```js
const data = [
    {
        "levelNumber": "2",
        "name": "abc",
    },
    {
        "levelNumber": "3",
        "name": "abc"
    },
    { 
        "levelNumber": "3",
        "name": "raks",
    },
    { 
        "levelNumber": "4",
        "name": "raks",
    },
    { 
        "levelNumber": "5",
        "name": "raks",
    }
];

// 1.
const names = new Set(data.map((item) => item.name)); // Set is used to get only unique items

// 2.
const result = []; // For normal JS
// const result: Array<{levelNumber: string, name: string}> = []; // For TS

// 3.
names.forEach((name) => {
    /* minify data (filter items with only particular name) e.g. [{levelNumber: '2', name: 'abc'}, {levelNumber: '3', name: 'abc'}] */
    const minifiedData = data.filter((item) => item.name === name);

    /* same process, now for minified array */
    const levelNumbers = minifiedData.map((item) => parseInt(item.levelNumber));
    const maxLevelNumber = Math.max(...levelNumbers).toString();

    minifiedData.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.levelNumber == maxLevelNumber)
            result.push(item);  // push every matching item (item with highest level) in final result
    });
});

// 4.
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)
const levelNumbers: string[]

Comment: it is giving this error below answer code

Comment: ok so you're using typescript. I've updated my answer to work in TS as well!

Comment: test this code in JS or TS, it will work

Comment: hey @TalESid.. if i add one more object in the array of name = 'raks &  levelNumber = '4'  then it should display maximum levelNumber wrt that particular name.

Comment: say the result array should be:           {
        "levelNumber": "3",
        "name": "abc"
    }, {
        "levelNumber": "4",
        "name": "raks"
    }

Comment: can you help me with this please

Comment: absolutely, check my EDIT in the answer!

Comment: display maximum levelNumber wrt that particular name.. this is not working if I add one more object say,  { "levelNumber": "4", "name": "raks" }

Comment: have you checked the second snippet? it is running as you said

Comment: on adding that above object,..it will show only one result ..in my use case it should not eliminate one with name : 'abc' which has max level number as 3      .                                         so the end result should be name -> mapped to max level number (all 'name' to be presented)

Comment: answer has 2 snippets, run the last one, it returns both items i.e. abc with 3 and raks with 5

Comment: it has sample data as well. check the ***"SECOND ONE"***

Comment: oh i missed that.. new to stakoverflow haha ..let me check

Comment: yes. it will take

Comment: THANKS A LOT! you had given with explanation!

Comment: glad I helped :)

Comment: don't forget to upvote and mark correct. Thanks

Comment: Done already.. thanks again! looks like i cant upvote as I need some minimum reputation!

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the max level of all the objects in the array and then filter the array

```js
arr1 = [
{
    "levelNumber": "2",
    "name": "abc",
},
{
    "levelNumber": "3",
    "name": "abc"
},
{ 
    "levelNumber": "3",
    "name": "raks",
}
]
const maxLevel = String(Math.max(...arr1.map(obj => Number(obj.levelNumber))))
const maxLevelObjects = arr1.filter(obj => obj.levelNumber === maxLevel)
console.log(maxLevelObjects);
```

Comment: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)

Comment: its giving me this issue

Comment: updated the post to cast to Number in order to avoid the ts error

Comment: @nat if you're using TS then convert `levelNumber` to number before passing it to `Math.max`. Like this `const maxLevel = String(Math.max(...arr1.map(obj => +obj.levelNumber)))`

Comment: yes @transGLUKator see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const arr1 = [
      {
        levelNumber: '2',
        name: 'abc',
      },
      {
        levelNumber: '3',
        name: 'abc',
      },
      {
        levelNumber: '3',
        name: 'raks',
      },
    ];
    
    const getHighLevelElements = (array) => {
      if (array.length === 0) return null;
      array.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
        if (Number(elem1.levelNumber) < Number(elem2.levelNumber)) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (Number(elem1.levelNumber) > Number(elem2.levelNumber)) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    
      return array.filter((elem) => elem.levelNumber === array[0].levelNumber);
    };
    
    const resultArr = getHighLevelElements([...arr1]);
    console.log(resultArr);
```

Comment: its displaying all the three why? @Lior Kamisnky

Comment: it displaying only only the levelNumber: 3 elements - try to run the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I would first have a variable called `highestLevel` to store the ***highest level number found in the array of objects*** (will be used later while looping), loop through the whole array and checking every key `levelNumber` and storing that number ***IF*** `highestLevel` is lower than the value of the current object `levelNumber`.
After I've looped through the array and got the actual `highestLevel` number, I would loop through again and only get the objects that are equivalent to my variable `highestLevel`

Answer (score -1):

You can just iterate one time over `arr1` with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Code:

```js
const arr1 = [{levelNumber: '2',name: 'abc',},{levelNumber: '3',name: 'abc',},{levelNumber: '3',name: 'raks'}]

const result = arr1.reduce((a, c) => !a.length || +c.levelNumber === +a[0].levelNumber 
  ? [...a, c] 
  : +c.levelNumber > +a[0].levelNumber 
    ? [c] 
    : a, 
[])


console.log(result)
```

Comment: nice solution but not efficient at all, because this line [...a, c] will copy the entire existing array over each iteration